# Accessing user GMail Account through API

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I am writing this goroutine that'll call the GMail API and poll my inbox every 2 minutes or so.  The problem I am having trouble with is the authentication part because it'll need me to login and authenticate myself and give authorization to the app to read my inbox.  I am trying to eliminate the part where I will need to login via the Web UI and give access to my program.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to login and authenticate myself programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the steps here in order to generate and OAuth client ID, then use that to connect using oauth?:

https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth/blob/master/Example-macOS/README.md

Failing that, you could use IMAP access to bypass the api entirely. Turn on imap in settings and use a library like this to access your messages:

https://github.com/emersion/go-imap/blob/v1/README.md

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean by using IMAP to bypass the api?

Comment: added an example for imap

Comment: Thanks for that!  That's really helpful; just a small question though about that imap example.  Since I would be connecting to GMail's server, I would only need to worry about the client side code?  Also would another way just to get the authorization to my account before deploying and save the access token and refresh token in a database therefore allowing me to make calls without signing in again?

Comment: yes, and yes, but depends how long tokens last whether it would work for you.

Comment: I think that refresh tokens provided by Google never expire.  Could you confirm or deny if you know about that?

Comment: No idea, try it and see :)